# Java EE Ear application deployment failing -- javaDB persistance issue

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish-4, javadb, netbeans-8

I know why it's failing -- it can't find the resource I've specified in the persistence.xml file. Which is purely wrong. I created the database, and connected it to netbeans. What I don't know is why there's extra characters for the resource name in the errors below.

```
[2014-11-12T14:08:27.655-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] []     [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.dol] [tid: _ThreadID=354 _ThreadName=admin-listener(47)] [timeMillis: 1415826507655] [levelValue: 900] [[
This web app [/srv/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/default/applications/EmployeeScheduler-war/] has no resource reference by the name of [users]]]

[2014-11-12T14:08:27.690-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=354 _ThreadName=admin-listener(47)] [timeMillis: 1415826507690] [levelValue: 1000] [[
Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method]]

[2014-11-12T14:08:27.693-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=354 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1415826507693] [levelValue: 1000] [[
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource : users__nontx
```

The resource *should* exist and be available. Netbeans connected to it just fine. So why isn't the EAR finding it? What am I doing wrong? How do I fix.

Any other info needed just let me know.

Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="EmployeeScheduler-warPU_users" transaction-type="JTAs">
    <jta-data-source>users</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://domainaddress/users"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, Turns out the removing the below line from the persistence file let it work.

```
<jta-data-source>users</jta-data-source>
```